# select update within sama table oracle sql or pl/sql -

Tags: oracle11g

I need to select v_col1, from table_x and that column gives me string that i need to put(update) into same 
rowid but into diffrent column(h_col2) in sama table table_x - sorry it seems easy but i am beginner....

```
tabl_x 
rowid  V_col1,      h_col2     etc ..... 
1     672637263   GVRT1898
2     384738477   GVRT1876
3     263237863   GVRT1832
```

like in this example i need to put GVRT1898 (update) instead of 672637263 and i need to 
go into every row in this table_x and fix - 
like next line would be (rowid2 would be GVRT1876 instead of 384738477 :-) 
this table has 40000 lines like this and i need to loop for every rowid

THX for your responce Justin - this is a little more complex,

i have this string in h_col and need to take only GVRTnumber out and put into v_col - but it's 
hard becouse GVRTnumber is in various place in column see down here....

"E_ID"=X:"**GVRT1878**","RCode"=X:"156000","Month"=d:1,"Activate"=d:5,"Disp_Id"=X:"4673498","Tar"=X:"171758021";

2"E_ID"=X:"561001760","RCode"=X:"156000","Month"=d:1,"Activate"=d:5,"Disp_Id"=X:"**GVRT1898**","Tar"=X:"171758021";

h_col column have this number that i want but in various place like somethimes it's in this 600byte column it's in byte nr 156 - sometimes in 287 but the only unique is "GVRT...." how can i take that string and  put it to v_col -

Can you show me how to write such SQL pl/sql ?

regards & thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want

```
UPDATE tabl_x
   SET h_col2 = v_col1
```

Of course, if you do something like this, that implies that one of the two columns should be dropped or the data model needs to get fixed.  Having two copies of the same data in each row is a bad idea from a normalization standpoint if nothing else.